# How to seperate structures in bulk with connectivity from a relaxed scan in Gaussian 16?

Tags: gaussian, td-dft, potential-energy-surface

I aim is to construct the PES for a molecule considering a specific bond length as the scan coordinate. I am using the Relaxed-Scan feature of Gaussian 16 for this using the `opt=modredundant` keyword. Now, on successfully scanning the ground state PES, I wish to construct the same for the excited states via TDDFT. The way I use right now is very tedious ... I open the `scan.log` which is the output of the scan job in GaussView 6, I select the "frame" of a specific structure and I set up a new Gaussian TDDFT job. And I repeat it selecting every single frame using the GUI.

As you might have noticed, it is horribly inefficient as the number of structures become large. I am looking for ways to automate the "click the different frames and save a new job" part. Members of our groups tried writing scripts but it failed to include the connectivity along with the coordinates.

Another solution might be to run a job that can do both

1. Do the ground state relaxed scan
2. Do a TDDFT excitation at every structure of the scan after optimization

in a single job. The end goal is to plot the ground and excited state PES for the given coordinate (bond length in the problems we tackle).

Below is what the frame selection screen looks like in GV6
[image: Below is what the frame selection screen looks like in GV6]